# perl assign string on multiple lines

Tags: perl

I'd like to be able to assign the concatenation of multiple strings to a variable.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
$variable = 123
$string = "hello" +
          "this is a " +
          $variable +
          "string";
```

Is it possible to do something along these lines in perl?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [perlop #Additive Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Additive-Operators):

> #### Additive Operators
>
> Binary `+` returns the sum of two numbers.
> Binary `-` returns the difference of two numbers.
> Binary `.` concatenates two strings.

Therefore, for string concatenation you need:

```
$string = "hello" .
          "this is a " .
          $variable .
          "string";
```

Answer (score 3):

`+` does addition. `.` does concatenation.

```
my $variable = 123;
my $string = "hello" . 
             "this is a " .
             $variable .
             "string";
```